# Formatting double values for display

Tags: c#

How do I format this:

```
double salary = 12345.6789
```

to be displayed as this:

```
12,345.68
```

using `String.Format()` or any other methods?

I have tried

```
String.Format(value.To String("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)));
```

But this isn't what I am looking for, I want to append the currency (which is a local currency symbol not available in the .Net framework) to a string for display.I just need to be able to format the value.

Comment: Cue to 10 answers...

Comment: `string.Format("{0:n}", salary);`

Comment: When money is involved, use the variable type 'decimal' not 'double' to avoid problems. If the double is coming from an external system, convert it to a decimal first, then worry about formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`N` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#NFormatString) as;

```
double salary = 12345.6789;
Console.WriteLine(salary.ToString("N2"));
```

Result will be;

```
12,345.68
```

This specifier uses your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx)'s [`NumberGroupSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator(v=vs.110).aspx) properties by default. If these properties are not `,` and `.` in your `CurrentCulture`, you can provide [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx) to this `.ToString()` method as a second parameter like;

```
double salary = 12345.6789;
Console.WriteLine(salary.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass "N" into [`double.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var desiredString = salary.ToString("N");
```

Comment: This formats it using the currency sign of the current culture. That's not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You want to pass a format string to the `.ToString()` method.

```
salary.ToString("N");
```

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx) for more format options

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
String.Format("{0:0,0.0}", 12345.67);     // "12,345.7"
String.Format("{0:0,0}", 12345.67);       // "12,346"
```

More examples [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`N` standard format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#NFormatString), and specify two decimal places:

```
string formatted = salary.ToString("N2");
```

That will use the decimal separator and thousands separator of the current culture of the application. If you want to ensure that it always uses a period as decimal separator and a comma as thousands separator, you can specify the invariant culture:

```
string formatted = salary.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```